# C# Exception Handling: still getting Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I still get

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.

spits out to my screen. Unhandled? why?

```
string t="";
try
{ 
     t = line.Substring(236, 14);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Text: "+line+ ", Line Number: " +count);
}
```

this is what I get
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (from print to console)
Parameter name: startIndex
Text:     2933000000, Line Number: 13424  (from the second print to console)

and I still get this:
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Because that's what you are doing in your exception handler? `Console.WriteLine(e.Message);`.

Comment: because you catch an unhandled exeption to handle it? :)

Comment: I gotta go with @Oded here after your edit, what did you expect it to do? You're index is out of range so it's throwing an exception.

Comment: Anyway Substring doesn't throw IndexOutOfRangeException but **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** then I don't think the error is on that line. Together with the error message you may get the **full exception stack trace** too...

Comment: Don't print Line in the exception handler, if it's null it will cause a crash. Check for null first.

Comment: Please update your question with a [complete example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: the e.Message is outputting "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string". the "Unhandled Exception" is not from e.Message

Comment: When I run this code, I do not get the "Unhandled Exception" bit, just the message as expected. This suggests that your problem is elsewhere.